# Populate the content in between two words in Richtextbox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox, string-matching

I am very new to VS. And c#. Here I have Richtextbox. I want to filter it content which in between two words.

`This is the example way to do my processing. This text is on my Richtextbox`

I want to populate content in between word `example` and word `text`.
 Answer is  `way to do my processing. This`

Please help me doing this using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RegEx or, assuming `text` is your richtextbox text, this code:

```
string from = "example";
int iStart = text.IndexOf(from) + from.Length;
int iEnd = text.IndexOf("text", iStart);
string result = text.Substring(iStart, iEnd - iStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
string strTest = 
  "This is the example way to do my processing. This text is on my Richtextbox";
strTest = strTest.Substring(strTest.IndexOf("example") + 8);
strTest = strTest.Substring(0,strTest.IndexOf("text")-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to get the text out of the RichTextBox, try:

```
var textRange = new TextRange(
    richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, 
    richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
var text = textRange.Text;
```

and then...

(see other answers)

Comment: `answer` here starts with _example_ word and doesn't get all words required

Comment: @Marco: Oops, yes of course. I was focusing on the problem how to get the text out of RichTextBox. Sorry, my fault. To get the right Substring your solution is the right way.

Comment: it happened the same thing to me yesyerday :)